# Negative margin covering links underneath

Tags: hyperlink, z-index, margin

I have two divs, neither floated, and the bottom one has a negative margin on top (pulling it upwards). That bottom div is ‘covering’ some of the links in the div underneath. **I need links to work in both divs**, and z-index doesn’t seem to be working at all.

Again, neither div is floated, just the bottom div pulled up a bit with a negative margin on top and it’s ‘covering’ links in the div below it.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

The site in question is here: http://dawsondental.ca (see the footer)

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't believe it's actually possible to allow links in both layered divs to work. I have the divs relatively positioned so that z-index works, but regardless, layered is layered. It's not possible to have useable content in layered divs. Right? If anyone knows anything I'm missing, I'm all ears.

Thanks